# nhibernate is removing join in sub query

Tags: nhibernate

I'm working on a conversion project .net 2.0 to .net 4.5.1 and have run into an issue with NHibernate HQL. My problem is with a sub query that is added at run time which is stored in the database for filtering purposes and appended to the HQL before the query is tanslated by NH. The two left joins in the sub query are removed.

the query before translation:

```
Select allergy From Allergy allergy left  join allergy.HealthcareWorker healthcareWorker where (1=1)  and healthcareWorker.Id = :healthcareWorkerId and ((
allergy.Id in ( Select allergy.id From Allergy allergy
    left join allergy.HealthcareWorker healthcareWorker 
    left join healthcareWorker.LatticeFacility latticeFacility 
    Where latticeFacility.Id in (134,342))))
```

after transformation:

```
select allergy0_.AllergyID as AllergyID41_, allergy0_.RowVersionNumber as RowVersi2_41_, allergy0_.AllergyDate as AllergyD3_41_, allergy0_.Comments as Comments41_, allergy0_.InactivationDate as Inactiva5_41_, allergy0_.CreatedAt as CreatedAt41_, allergy0_.CreatedBy as CreatedBy41_, allergy0_.LastModAt as LastModAt41_, allergy0_.LastModBy as LastModBy41_, allergy0_.HealthcareWorkerID as Healthc10_41_, allergy0_.AllergyTypeID as Allergy11_41_, allergy0_.AllergySubstanceID as Allergy12_41_, allergy0_.MedicationItemID as Medicat13_41_, allergy0_.MedicalPractitionerConfirmedID as Medical14_41_, allergy0_.InactivationReasonID as Inactiv15_41_, case when allergy0_.InactivationDate is not null then case when allergy0_.InactivationReasonID is not null then 0 else 1 end else 1 end as formula4_ from tblAllergy allergy0_ left outer join tblHealthcareWorker healthcare1_ on allergy0_.HealthcareWorkerID=healthcare1_.HealthcareWorkerID where 1=1 and healthcare1_.HealthcareWorkerID=@p0 and (allergy0_.AllergyID in (select allergy2_.AllergyID from tblAllergy allergy2_ where latticefac4_.LatticeFacilityID in (134,342))
```

This generates an exception The multi-part identifier "latticefac4_.LatticeFacilityID" could not be bound. Obviously because the joins have been removed from the sub query.

I'm am new to NHibernate so any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So this ended up being an issue with NHibernate not recognising the table aliases. Turns out the sub query aliases for the joins need to be unique from the external query aliases.